# Why my Swift Tableview data doesn't work in another ViewController when I pass it from TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My tableview data doesn't work in another view controller when I pass it from a tableView. I can see the passed data in the console with print(), but it doesn't work when I want to use it.

Here is my TableView

```
import UIKit

class BroadcastList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var slider: UIBarButtonItem!

    var articles: [Article]? = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if(revealViewController() != nil)
        {
            slider.target = self.revealViewController()
            slider.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        }

        fetchArticles()
    }

    func fetchArticles(){
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myurl.com")!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            print(response)
            self.articles = [Article]()
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

                if let articlesFromJson = json["UserList"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson {
                        let article = Article()
                        if let title = articleFromJson["name"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["userid"] as? String, let desc = articleFromJson["startedt"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["liveURL"] as? String, let urlToImage = articleFromJson["image"] as? String, let streamID = articleFromJson["streamID"] as? String {

                            article.author = author
                            article.desc = desc
                            article.headline = title
                            article.url = url
                            article.streamID = streamID
                            article.imageUrl = urlToImage
                            //print(url)
                        }
                        self.articles?.append(article)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }

            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }


        }

        task.resume()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell

        cell.title.text = self.articles?[indexPath.item].headline
        cell.desc.text = self.articles?[indexPath.item].desc
        cell.author.text = self.articles?[indexPath.item].author
        cell.imgView.downloadImage(from: (self.articles?[indexPath.item].imageUrl!)!) 

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.articles?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let DestViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "watchLive") as! WatchLiveVideo
        let strmid = (self.articles?[indexPath.item].streamID)!
        let urlc = (self.articles?[indexPath.item].url)!
        print(urlc)
        DestViewController.getStreamID = strmid
        DestViewController.vgetURL = urlc
        self.present(DestViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}

extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImage(from url: String){

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
                self.clipsToBounds = true
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func downloadImageSquare(from url: String){

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

My another ViewController code is here.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
//import MediaPlayer

class WatchLiveVideo: UIViewController {

    var getStreamID = ""
    var vgetURL = ""
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var player: AVPlayer?

    var team1S = ""
    var team2S = ""

    //var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController!

    @IBOutlet var playerholder: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var vPlayer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var teamA: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var teamB: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var team2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var team1: UILabel!

    var count: Int = 1;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.playerholder.layer.zPosition = 1;

        team1.text = "0"
        team2.text = "0"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(WatchLiveVideo.self.getScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://35.160.212.231:1935/live/shopno/playlist.m3u8")

        let videoURL = NSURL(string: vgetURL)
        print(videoURL)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as! URL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        vPlayer.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = vPlayer.frame
        player.play()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func getScore() {

        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://myurl.com");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        //input data bind to send server

        //let streamID = "88"
        let streamID = self.getStreamID

        let postString = "streamID=\(streamID)"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let title = parseJSON["team1"] as? String
                    let title2 = parseJSON["team2"] as? String

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.team1.text = title
                        self.team2.text = title2
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

Comment: Please describe more detailed. What "data" doe you pass, what "does not work", what data can you see with with print()?

Comment: You should use `indexPath.row` for a tableview, not `indexPath.item`

Comment: @shallowThought, Here I passed 'getStreamID', and 'vgetURL' from tableview. When I do 'print(getStreamID)' and 'print(vgetURL)' then I can see my passed value in the console as String, but when I want to use 'vgetURL' as an URL to load video like this way 'let videoURL = NSURL(string: vgetURL)' then it doesn't load anything but it is working when I use 'let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://35.160.212.231:1935/live/shopno/playlist.m3u8")'. And for 'getStreamID', if I use static value in 'let streamID = "88" ' then it work but when I use 'let streamID = self.getStreamID' then it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Problem solved, here my code is ok. I was segue connected from the UITableViewCell, I just delete it now everything is ok.